# How can I implement partial transpose on a variable in Picos (Python, trying to solve an SDP)?

Tags: programming, optimization, semidefinite-programming, partial-transpose

I try to optimise a quantity via an SDP. I optimise over all PPT measurement operators and hence have the constraints $\Pi_k^{T_B} \succeq 0$ (PPT) for my measurement operators.

The part of the code where I define the SDP and constraints is:

```
[...]

# Defining the SDP
p = pic.Problem()
pic.new_param("rho_0", rho_0)
pic.new_param("rho_1", rho_1)
pic.new_param("rho_2", rho_2)

# Measurement operators
P_0 = p.add_variable("P_0", (9,9), "hermitian")
P_1 = p.add_variable("P_1", (9,9), "hermitian")
P_2 = p.add_variable("P_2", (9,9), "hermitian")
P_inc = p.add_variable("P_inc", (9,9), "hermitian")

# Partial transposes
p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_0, 3, 3) >> 0)
p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_1, 3, 3) >> 0)
p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_2, 3, 3) >> 0)
p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_inc, 3, 3) >> 0)

[...]
```

where `PT_B` is a function implementing the partial transpose, i.e.

```
def PT_B(M, d1, d2):
    """
    Partial Transpose map of M
    Input: Matrix M, Dimension d1 of subsystem 1, Dimension d2 of subsystem 2
    Output: Partial Transpose M_TB
    """
    assert M.shape == (d1 * d2, d1 * d2)

    # Reshape into 4 tensor
    M = M.reshape(d1, d2, d1, d2)

    # Transpose 2nd system
    M = M.transpose((0, 3, 2, 1))

    # Reshape back into a density matrix
    return M.reshape(d1 * d2, d1 * d2)
```

However, Picos doesn't let me manipulate the variable expressions. I also tried to implement the partial transpose by setting the elements of a new variable by hand to the elements of $\Pi_k^{T_B}$. But then Picos tells me that I can't slice variable expressions.

The error message for the above SDP code snippet I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-36083f3fb159> in <module>
     12 
     13 # Partial transposes
---> 14 p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_0, 3, 3) >> 0)
     15 p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_1, 3, 3) >> 0)
     16 p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_2, 3, 3) >> 0)

<ipython-input-34-2327f6ca6850> in PT_B(M, d1, d2)
      5     Output: Partial Transpose M_TB
      6     """
----> 7     assert M.shape == (d1 * d2, d1 * d2)
      8 
      9     # Reshape into 4 tensor

AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

If I try to force the variable expression into an np.array:

```
[...]

# Partial transposes
p.add_constraint(PT_B(np.array(P_0), 3, 3) >> 0)
p.add_constraint(PT_B(np.array(P_1), 3, 3) >> 0)
p.add_constraint(PT_B(np.array(P_2), 3, 3) >> 0)
p.add_constraint(PT_B(np.array(P_inc), 3, 3) >> 0)

[...]
```

Then I get the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-c6e549dceb23> in <module>
     12 
     13 # Partial transposes
---> 14 p.add_constraint(PT_B(np.array(P_0), 3, 3) >> 0)
     15 p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_1, 3, 3) >> 0)
     16 p.add_constraint(PT_B(P_2, 3, 3) >> 0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/picos/expressions.py in __getitem__(self, index)
   3973         JJ = rangeT
   3974         VV = [1.] * nsz
-> 3975         newfacs = {self: spmatrix(VV, II, JJ, (nsz, sz))}
   3976         if not self.constant is None:
   3977             newcons = self.constant[rangeT]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/picos/tools.py in spmatrix(*args, **kwargs)
   2187     """
   2188     try:
-> 2189         return cvx.spmatrix(*args, **kwargs)
   2190     except TypeError as error:
   2191         # CVXOPT does not like NumPy's int64 scalar type for indices, so attempt

TypeError: dimension too small
```

Does anyone have an idea how to implement the PPT constraint in the SDP in Python?

Mathematica doesn't allow complex matrix SDPs, and Picos and CVXPY give me a hard time implementing the PPT constraint.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: In fact, I just found that there is an in-built partial transpose in Picos. Then it works. See `https://picos-api.gitlab.io/picos/api/autogen/picos.partial_transpose.html?highlight=partial%20transpose#picos.partial_transpose`.